# Need help adding Expires headers

Tags: http, caching, performance, yslow

So basically I've ran my site through ySlow and it has informed me that I should add Expires headers to some of the elements on my page to help with the caching. The page is mainly static content currently hosted on an Apache/2 server.

If it helps at all the site is [here](http://www.polyrowing.co.uk/indexhome.html).

I'm not really sure how you alter the HTTP information or what the best way to add Expires headers is so I would greatly appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mod_expires module of Apache2 to set the Expires header on your semi-static files. For reference: [mod_expires documentation on apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

Comment: Yeah I came across that method in my searching and agree that it sounds like the best solution on my server. I am still not sure however how I would go about implementing this and have found very little explanation around on how to do this.

I'm afraid I've got very little experience in this area. 

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The reference document Mark links to has specific examples of how to use the Apache module to set an expires field - both a default one and a per-type value for various mime types.

Comment: Okay thanks Mark I will have another read through the documentation and see if I can make more sense of it.